# Which HTML elements support onerror attribute?

Tags: javascript, css, onerror

I have a site that loads CSS and fonts from [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts/).  However, one place where the site will be used is a local intranet with no Internet access.

I still want to use the fonts from Google where I can for the benefits that Google offers, such as the fonts being downloaded from a CDN and possibly already being cached on the user's computer from visits to another site that uses them.

I also use [Google-hosted jQuery](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) and I use the following code (from [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html)) to load jQuery from my server if Google is not accessible:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

I am looking for a way to do the same for CSS files.

I have used `<img src="..." onerror="..." />` in the past for handling images that don't load, so I was wondering if I can use that for stylesheets that don't load too.  I did a quick test in a few browsers, using  `<link href="..." onerror="..." rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`, and the `onerror` was executed in all of them, but I would like to find out if I can expect this to work consistently in all browsers.  *Or is there a better way to do it?*

I saw several other answers here that discuss watching the `document.styleSheets` collection, but that sounds like much more of a hack than this does.

---

Note: This is really more of a "is this practical and do people use it"-question than a "what does the spec have to say about it"-question.

Comment: I've never used it, but then again, I didn't know it existed, so...

Comment: The quirksmode page (http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/error.html) says that it is not supported, but those are mostly old versions, so it appears that there have been changes. You can try your browser on their test page: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/tests/error.html

Comment: @PitaJ I actually found out about it when someone used it for a cross-site scripting attack on a forum that a class I was in used. The forum software filtered out javascript in `<script>` tags and `onclick` properties, etc., but did not filter out the `onerror` property. A student used that flaw to obtain all the session cookies and was impersonating an instructor for some time before anyone found out.

Comment: @yakatz you make a list of whitelisted attributes for each of your whitelisted elements (preferably making sure that the attributes required for valid x/HTML/5 are available) or at least filter out **every** _on\*_ attribute.

Comment: @PaulS. I know that, but the developer of the forum software did not. I almost always use whitelists. That mostly protects you from new standards (like HTML5).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the list of [supported events on `<script>` and `<link>` at pieisgood](http://pieisgood.org/test/script-link-events/) is what you're looking for.

As you can see, *onload* is the most widely supported for `<link>` which is very lacking in working events. But you could try to implement an error event by having *onload* `clearTimeout` for some function that assumes an error happened.

Comment: It looks like the list there is not entirely accurate (for example, `link onerror` *partially* works in IE10), but it is the best I've been able to find.

Answer (score 0):

`<link>`, `<style>`, and `<script>` all support the `onerror` attribute, and work in most modern/popular browsers.

A small caveat with `<link>` is that it will trigger the onerror event for either when the href URI is broken, or if any `@import` URIs in the linked stylesheet are broken.

The only way I found to trigger the `onerror` event for `<style>` was by using `@import`.

A broken `@font-face` does not seem to trigger the event for either tag.